# Displaying an img from database using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Is there any way to display an BLOB image from database ?

I've tried this but not working:

```
 <?print'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,. base64_encode($img["Imag"])">  '; ?>
```

Comment: you are using `"` inside `"` as `["Imag"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $img['Imag'] ).'"/>';
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your `concatination` also don't use `print` in this scenario use `echo`.

```
 echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.  $img['Imag'] .'"/>';
```

**OR**

```
 echo '<img src='.base64_encode ($img ["Imag"].' />';
```

Comment: try without base64_encode as I updated in my answer. if this also not works then the image u saved in database will truncated due to limited size. Give the image column varchar (50000). and try to save again the image. Then it will work